# Every propositional logic has a matrix semantics. Are there any that can't be described with a single matrix?

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, propositional-calculus

I am reading [this paper](https://moraschini.github.io/files/submitted/Leibniz-Hierarchy.pdf).

Theorem 2.1 on page 3 says that *every logic has a matrix semantics*.

A matrix is a pair $\langle \mathcal{A}, X \rangle$ where $\mathcal{A}$ is an algebraic structure and $X$ is a subset of $A$ called the designated elements or designated truth values.

A *matrix semantics* is a whole class of these things where the algebras are all similar (have the same language).

A logic $\mathcal{S}$ in this case is a pair consisting of a language $\mathcal{L}$ and a consequence relation $\vdash_{\mathcal{S}}$.

I'm assuming that $\vdash_{\mathcal{S}}$ is a deductive system, subject to the following rules. These rules are mostly paraphrased from Blok and Pigozzi's *Algebraizable Logics*, but I don't have the book in front of me at the moment.

Let $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ hold if and only if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ for all $\varphi$ in $\Delta$.

1. *substitution closure*: For all substitutions $\sigma$, if $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ then $\sigma(\Gamma) \vdash \sigma(\varphi)$.
2. *monotonicity of entailment*: $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ implies $\Delta \cup \Gamma \vdash \varphi$.
3. *identity*: $\varphi \vdash \varphi$
4. *transitivity*: If $\Gamma \vdash \Delta$ and $\Delta \vdash \varphi$ then $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$.
5. *compactness*: If $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ then there exists a finite $\Gamma_0 \subset \Gamma$ such that $\Gamma_0 \vdash \varphi$.

Anyway, the following explicit matrix semantics is given for an **arbitrary** deductive system.

$$ M := \{ \langle \textbf{Fm}, \Gamma \rangle : \Gamma \in \text{Th}(\vdash) \} $$

$\textbf{Fm}$ is the formula algebra, a completely free algebra on the language of the propositional logic. And $\text{Th}(\vdash)$ are the set of theories of $\vdash$. A theory is defined as a deductively closed set.

So, that makes sense and is actually quite clever. We can take an arbitrary deductive system and turn it into a whole mess of matrices by taking the formula algebra as our algebra and choosing each possible deductively closed set in it in turn as our designated truth values.

**However**, some propositional logics such as classical logic, intuitionistic logic, and minimal logic can have their semantics completely described by a **single matrix**.

Indeed matrix semantics-es where the class is a singleton don't seem to be mentioned in (the first few pages of) Moraschini's paper, but this seems like an interesting special case.

Anyway, this raises the question:

**Are there propositional logics with a matrix semantics that can't be described with a single matrix?**

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but from one point of view, it seems a bit odd to say that "these are the truth values", if we define/understand a logic as a system of axioms under some rule(s) of inference.  For instance, if we start with Frege's axioms *only* (not his description of semantics in his text), does that imply two truth values for the logic?  No, since it got shown by Bochvar that there existed a three-valued semantics which could act similarly to classical two-valued semantics.

Comment: @DougSpoonwood I'm afraid I don't really understand your comment. In this setting, we aren't identifying a logic with its axioms and inference rules. Instead we're saying that a logic is any binary relation on $(\text{Set of formulas}, \text{formulas})$, subject to a few constraints. We're also not using the matrix semantics-es one at a time; we're using a whole class of them, similar to using the Boolean algebras as a whole as a semantics for classical logic. Individual matrices may be 1 or 2 or $n$-valued, but the logic as a whole isn't $n$-valued.

Comment: What is the matrix used for intuitionist logic?

Comment: @MarkSaving The matrix consisting of the open sets on the standard topology of $\mathbb{R}$ with $\mathbb{R}$ as the sole designated truth value. This is the [first explicit semantics given in this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionistic_logic#Semantics).

Comment: There are other possible single-matrix semantics for IPC (and there's definitely at least one per infinite cardinal by Löwenheim–Skolem).